# ListView Returns The Same Data

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I've made a mini chat in my application using Parse. The only problem I seem to run into is when I write a message twice:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmdJq.png

As you can see in the 2 photos, it will make both chat posts the same message. I'm wondering what I could be doing wrong? Here's the code I think is involved:

MainActivity.java

```
public void onClick(View v){

    TimelineBaseAdapter myAdapter = new TimelineBaseAdapter(context, myList);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.timelineListView);
    lv.setAdapter(new TimelineBaseAdapter(context, myList));

    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    String post = et.getText().toString();

    ParseObject po = new ParseObject("Posts");
    po.put("Comments", post);
    po.saveInBackground();

    this.retrievedPost = po.getString("Comments");

    getDataInList();

    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void getDataInList(){

   TimelineListData tld = new TimelineListData();
   tld.setPost(retrievedPost);

   myList.add(tld);

}

}
```

TimelineBaseAdapter.java

```
public class TimelineBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<TimelineListData> myList = new ArrayList<>();
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

public TimelineBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList myList){
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TimelineListData tld2 = getItem(position);

    String settingPost = tld2.post;

    MyViewHolder myViewHolder;

    if (convertView == null){

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post, null);
        myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
        myViewHolder.chatpost = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chatpost);
        convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);

    }

    else {

        myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    }

    myViewHolder.chatpost.setText(settingPost);

    return convertView;

}

private static class MyViewHolder{
    TextView chatpost;

}
}
```

TimelineListData.java

```
public class TimelineListData {

static String post;

public String getPost() {

    ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Posts");

    return post.getString("Comments");
}

public void setPost(String post) {
    TimelineListData.post = post;
}
}
```

All help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you reduce the code to the minimum required to solve the problem?  This will make it easier for people to find the problem and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your help, but the problem was that the String post in TimelineListData.java was static. When I removed static, they were no longer repeating the same data.

Answer (score 0):

in getView, change

```
 TimelineListData tld2 = new TimelineListData();
```

with

```
 TimelineListData tld2 = getItem(position);
```

From the perspective of the ViewHolder pattern, the following line

```
 myViewHolder.chatpost = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chatpost);
```

goes inside the guard:

```
  if (convertView == null)
```

after

```
myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested which looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/66FGBdke

But I still seem to get the same result of the double posts

Answer (score 0):

You are setting two different adapters for the listview

```
TimelineBaseAdapter myAdapter = new TimelineBaseAdapter(context, myList);
```

Change this

```
lv.setAdapter(new TimelineBaseAdapter(context, myList));
```

to

```
lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```